# change the namespace of an element with xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I'd like to make this

```
<hello>
  <one>
    <paragraph>p1</paragraph>
  </one>
</hello>
```

into this

```
<x:hello y:an_attribute="a value for an_attribute" xmlns:x="some_new_namespace" xmlns:y="other_ns">
  <one>
    <paragraph>p1</paragraph>
  </one>
</x:hello>
```

this is the stylesheet I came up with:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:param name="element_localname" select="'hello'"/>


    <xsl:template match="node()">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="local-name() = $element_localname">
                <xsl:element name="{$element_localname}" namespace="some_new_namespace">
                    <xsl:attribute name="an_attribute" namespace="other_ns">a value for an_attribute</xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:when>

            <!-- copy the rest as is -->
            <xsl:otherwise> 
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:otherwise>

        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

but for some strange reason, the attribute I am adding to the element has the same namespace as the root element itself? why?

```
<ns0:hello xmlns:ns0="other_ns" ns0:an_attribute="a value for an_attribute">
  <one>
    <paragraph>p1</paragraph>
  </one>
</ns0:hello>
```

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Running your source through your transformation in xsltproc gives me `<hello xmlns="some_new_namespace" xmlns:ns_1="other_ns" ns_1:an_attribute="a value for an_attribute">` for the `hello` element, which seems to be what you're wanting. Wonder if this is an XSL 1.0 versus XSL 2.0 thing?

Comment: Thanks for trying. I am using the eclipse wtp build in xslt processor. I have no idea what implementation that uses.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a much simpler and shorter solution than the currently accepted one. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:x="some_new_namespace"
    xmlns:y="other_ns">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:param name="element_localname" select="'hello'"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="local-name() = $element_localname">
                <xsl:element name="x:{$element_localname}">
                    <xsl:attribute name="y:an_attribute">
                        <xsl:text>a value for an_attribute</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:call-template name="identity" />
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<x:hello y:an_attribute="a value for an_attribute"
         xmlns:y="other_ns" xmlns:x="some_new_namespace">
    <one>
        <paragraph>p1</paragraph>
    </one>
</x:hello>
```

Comment: Thank you, this works. You solved my problem :) Do you have an idea why my example does not?

Comment: @Luca: You are wellcome. This is your code output: `<hello auto-ns1:an_attribute="a value for an_attribute" xmlns:auto-ns1="other_ns" xmlns="some_new_namespace"><one xmlns=""><paragraph>p1</paragraph></one></hello>` So, you have a defalut namespace root element with an attribute under a not null namespace (prefix is auto added by Namespaces Fixup) and a reset default namespace declaration `xmlns=""` (In XML 1.1 also prefixed namespaces declaration can be reseted.). Bottom line: if you want an specific prefix-namespace URI binding, declare that into the stylesheet.

Answer (score 4):

**This is much simpler than it might seem**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:x="some_new_namespace" xmlns:y="other_ns"
 exclude-result-prefixes="x y">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <x:hello y:an_attribute="a value for an_attribute">
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </x:hello>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied to the provided XML document**:

```
<hello>
    <one>
        <paragraph>p1</paragraph>
    </one>
</hello>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<x:hello xmlns:x="some_new_namespace" xmlns:y="other_ns" y:an_attribute="a value for an_attribute">
    <one>
        <paragraph>p1</paragraph>
    </one>
</x:hello>
```