# get rid of old namespace with xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I am am new to xslt. I am trying to convert XML from one schema into another schema. I want to "get rid" of the old namespace after the transform. How can I erase the old schema after the transform if I need it for the transform itself. Essentially, I want `http://positionskillmanagementservice.webservices.com` to go away and be replaced entirely by `http://newschema` (after I re-name the nodes). I am able to do most of what I want via Dimitre Novatchev's method from: [change the namespace of an element with xslt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4106275/change-the-namespace-of-an-element-with-xslt)

This is the XML:

```
<ns:positionSkillResponse xmlns:ns="http://positionskillmanagementservice.webservices.com">
<ns:return>1</ns:return>
<ns:return>9</ns:return>
</ns:positionSkillResponse>
```

This is the xslt:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ns="http://positionskillmanagementservice.webservices.com"
  version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" />

  <xsl:template match="ns:return">
    <parameter>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </parameter>
  </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="ns:position">
    <parameter>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </parameter>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ns:positionSkillResponse">
    <positionSkillRequest >
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </positionSkillRequest >
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>    

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am checking the work with [this tool](http://www.xslfiddle.net/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempt is way too specific. Try this more general one:

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:ns_old="http://positionskillmanagementservice.webservices.com"
>    
    <xsl:output method="xml" />

    <!-- matches any node not handled elsewhere -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>    

    <!-- matches elements in the old namespace, re-creates them in the new -->
    <xsl:template match="ns_old:*">
        <xsl:element name="ns:{local-name()}" namespace="http://newschema">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- if you don't have namespaced attributes you won't need this template -->
    <xsl:template match="@ns_old:*">
        <xsl:attribute name="ns:{local-name()}" namespace="http://newschema">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which delivers:

```
<ns:positionSkillResponse xmlns:ns="http://newschema">
    <ns:return>1</ns:return>
    <ns:return>9</ns:return>
</ns:positionSkillResponse>
```

Notes

- You don't need to declare `xmlns:ns="http://newschema"` in the XSLT because you don't actually have nodes from that namespace in your input document.
- This also means you could declare the old namespace as `xmlns:ns="http://positionskillmanagementservice.webservices.com"` and use it like `<xsl:template match="ns:*">`. It's all the same to the XSL processor, but it's probably less confusing to the human reader if a different prefix like `ns_old` is used.
- You can choose your output prefix arbitrarily (`<xsl:element name="ns:{local-name()}" ...`). This has nothing to do with declared namespaces in the XSLT. Using no prefix at all would result in a document with a default namespace:

  ```
  <positionSkillResponse xmlns="http://newschema">
      <return>1</return>
      <return>9</return>
  </positionSkillResponse>
  ```

Answer (score 2):

Tomalak has shown you a better way to write your transformation, but hasn't really answered your immediate question. When you use literal result elements in your stylesheets, for example `<a>...</a>`, they are copied to the output together with all the namespaces that are in scope for that element in the stylesheet, with a few exceptions. One of the exceptions is that namespaces are omitted if they are listed in the exclude-result-prefixes element, which is usually placed on the xsl:stylesheet element along with the namespace declaration. So if you weren't refactoring the stylesheet as Tomalak suggests, you could have dropped the namespace by adding exclude-result-prefixes="ns" to the xsl:stylesheet element.